# Send private messages to users without API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messages

is there a way to send messages to users on facebook without using the API, like you can send email to users?

I have the users facebook email, but when i send to the facebook email, it sometimes go in the spam, sometime inbox and sometimes it dosen't even send to them, and I can see in Mandrill that the message is send?

Comment: I read somewhere that any message that comes from outside the world into the Facebook mail, it is sent to spam most of the times. Until the mail corresponds to a User's friend or someone on Facebook.

Comment: Yes, but even sometimes it dosent get into spam. So thats odd.

Comment: Platform Policies explicitly state that apps are __not__ supposed to use the _username@facebook.com_ email addresses to communicate with their users – so any complaining about undesired behavior when doing so is kinda pointless. Use requests if your want to motivate the user to do something in your app, or notifications if you just want to alert them to something. Those are the designated channels.